# How do I configure my rails app to utilize React?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am unable to get JSX from my React components to render to my view

So far I have:

Gotten the rails app running

Added 'react-rails' to my gemfile, and installed it

installed react via the rails console

created a simple database with some dummy data and migrated

generated, and wrote a simple react component

created a controller and view for the component I want to mount

wrote the view to look like:

```
<%= react_component 'Applications', { data: @applications } %>
```

and when I render the page I get:

```
 <div data-react-class="Applications" data-react-props="{&quot;data&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:1,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2019-07- 
  13&quot;,&quot;company&quot;:&quot;Epicodus&quot;,&quot;job_title&quot;:
 null,&quot;application_complete&quot;:true,&quot;salary 
 &quot;:50000,&quot;did_get_contact&quot;:false,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2019-07- 
14T06:23:52.220Z&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2019-07-14T06:23:52.220Z&quot;}]}"></div>
```

So it does see my component and gives it the proper data, however none of the raw jsx renders.

Comment: Have you added javascript_pack_tag in your layout?

Comment: I have not done so. I'll look into that.